# Remove window borders and unity panels

Tags: unity, launcher, games, steam

I have a multi-monitor setup with two screens. I'd like to stream a game with OBS, but still be able to use my second screen. If I run the game in fullscreen, I can un-capture mouse and keyboard with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (showing me the Steam overlay). But as soon as I click outside of the game, the recording of the game is missing a part of the game screen (although the steam overlay is still completely visible)

If I put the game into window mode, tabbing out works like it should, but, well, the game is in a window not in full screen, and therefore, the bottom and left part are incomplete due to the window having FullHD resolution (the Unity panels are in the way).

Can I somehow, on Ubuntu 16.10, remove the title bar of one single application and make that application overlap both the Unity launcher (the thing on the left with the program icons) and the Unity title bar (the thing on the top with WiFi, Network, Date, User, etc.)? I want the game to run in window mode, but still using the complete screen without using any window decorations - I can't use actual fullscreen mode cause that messes up the capture if I do something on the other screen.

I could use the Ubuntu configuration "Screen Display" to make the launcher appear on just one screen - but that doesn't make the title bar of the window go away, nor does it hide Unity's title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me being a a little indirect here, after doing a bit of research, something came to mind, have you considered using xpra, xnest or Xephyr to launch your unity session on one of your heads, you could use another Xephyr session for your application if necessary, even using a more appropriate window manager

you can also make use of the DISPLAY="" variable here, so you could launch your app in your Unity launcher, and display it in a separate screen

Ill will use Xephyr as an example here, as it comes bundled default with Ubuntu, you will need to install xdotool to follow my example, you could use xprop to get similar results i believe

Logout of your user and stop/disable lightdm, or whatever you use to manage your X login

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

you may want to create an .xinitrc file

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1024x768 :2 &
Xephyr -ac -screen 1024x768 :3 &
sleep 1
xdotool windowmove `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "Xephyr on :3.0"` 1024 0
DISPLAY=:2 unity
DISPLAY=:3 *application in other window*
```

you will execute startx

```
startx
```

adjust your properties accordingly, maybe you aren't using a 1024/768 display, the size of the display is whatever you want, and the xdotool is used to move the second Xephyr display across to your second head

I doubt this will work as is, but I didn't see anyone else giving an answer, it's better then nothing ;-)

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)